# Expecting a token named "token

Tags: javascript, angularjs, satellizer

I can't figure out what's causing this error with https://github.com/sahat/satellizer

satellize.js configurations

```
        withCredentials: !1,
        tokenRoot: null,
        cordova: !1,
        baseUrl: "/#",
        loginUrl: "/auth/login",
        signupUrl: "/auth/signup",
        unlinkUrl: "/auth/unlink/",
        tokenName: 'token',
        tokenPrefix: "satellizer",
        authHeader: "Authorization",
        authToken: "Bearer",
        storageType: "localStorage",
```

app.js
.config(function($authProvider) {

```
  $authProvider.facebook({
    clientId: '******'
  });
   $authProvider.google({
      clientId: '****'
   });


})
```

controller

```
  $scope.socialLogin = function(provider) {
     $auth.authenticate(provider)
    .then(function(data) {

      toastr.success('You have successfully signed in with ' + provider + '!');
      $rootScope.$broadcast('session',2)
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      if (error.error) {
        // Popup error - invalid redirect_uri, pressed cancel button, etc.
        toastr.error(error.error);
      } else if (error.data) {
        // HTTP response error from server
        toastr.error(error.data.message, error.status);
      } else {
        toastr.error(error);
      }
    });
};
```

expecting a token named token error here

service is called on broadcast
api/me 404 error here

```
 var app = angular.module('app');
   app.factory('Account', function($http) {
     return {
       getProfile: function() {
    return $http.get('api/me');
  },
  updateProfile: function(profileData) {
    return $http.put('api/me', profileData);
  }
   };
  });
```

I've tried all the variations on the github page there doesn't seem to be a solid solution for this.

Thought it might be because of the # in the url
changed the base url to /# and got error.

I added

```
  $locationProvider.html5Mode({
      enabled: true,
      requireBase: false
  });
```

that doesn't work either, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Which server side language you are using ?

Comment: Check this link ans http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34835506/unknown-reason-for-jwt-tokens-invalidation/34840448#34840448

Answer (score 1):

I think the error is when you are returning a JSON response from your server.
the format of the JSON response should be in the format.

```
    { "token" : "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJ0b3B0YWwuY29tIiwiZXhwIjoxNDI2NDIwODAwLCJodHRwOi8vdG9wdGFsLmNvbS9qd3RfY2xhaW1zL2lzX2FkbWluIjp0cnVlLCJjb21wYW55IjoiVG9wdGFsIiwiYXdlc29tZSI6dHJ1ZX0.yRQYnWzskCZUxPwaQupWkiUzKELZ49eM7oWxAQK_ZXw"}
```

so check what JSON response you are getting. and if you need more info on it check the **issues** tab of the GitHub link you have provided.