# Unknown Reason for JWT Tokens invalidation

Tags: angularjs, laravel, jwt, angular-http-interceptors, satellizer

I'm facing very weird problem with my laravel-Angular application. I'm using Tymon JWT to refresh token on my every request. I'm using `Satellizer` library to handle these JWT-Tokens, however, `Satellizer` doesn't seem to have a response interceptor to capture the new token. Hence I wrote my own Interceptor to do so.

```
.factory('ResponseHttpInterceptor', function ($window) {
    return {
        response: function (response) {
            if (response.headers('Authorization') != null) {
                $window.localStorage.removeItem('satellizer_token');
                $window.localStorage.setItem('satellizer_token', response.headers('Authorization').replace('Bearer ', ''));
            }
            return response;
        }
    }
})
```

This code basically captures the new token and replaces the existing token in local storage with the new token.

My test flow is:

```
Login -> Make who Am I call -> Logout
```

Upon Logout I receive an error `Invalid token` (**this doesn't happen always. Sometimes the flow succeeds and sometimes it fails**). This flow works perfect via REST Client postman. So I don't think there is any problem in my API's

Attaching image showing the new token being passed, after it is refreshed after my `whoami` call.

[image]

[image]

Upon logout I'm clearing the local storage. Can Anyone tell me what could be the reason for this?

**EDIT**

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'api/v1_0'], function () {
   Route::post('login', 'Auth\AuthControllerGeneral@postLogin');
   Route::get('logout', ['middleware' => 'jwt.auth', 'uses' =>    'Auth\AuthControllerGeneral@getLogout']);

   Route::group(['middleware' => ['jwt.refresh', 'jwt.auth']], function() {
       Route::get('whoami', 'Auth\AuthControllerGeneral@loggedInUserInfo');
   });
});
```

Comment: Share your htcacess and auth controller

Comment: Not on production server. Using `PHP artisan serve` to run server.

Comment: Why do you need `AuthController`? I mean, that's a general Controller. I'll share my routes. Please look at the edit.

Answer (score 0):

Check you htaccess you should have below code there

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)
RewriteRule .* - [e=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]
```

And AuthContrller is same as https://github.com/sahat/satellizer/blob/master/examples/server/php/app/Http/Controllers/AuthController.php

And Some people forget to check Authenticate middleware. Check this also

https://github.com/sahat/satellizer/blob/master/examples/server/php/app/Http/Middleware/Authenticate.php

I suggest first try with default route as in demo
https://github.com/sahat/satellizer/blob/master/examples/server/php/app/Http/routes.php

And still you not get the solution then try with sample client end folder.
https://github.com/sahat/satellizer/tree/master/examples/client

Which you can put in your laravel public folder just to test.

I found everything working fine in satellizer but some people fails in configuring this.

Comment: I've read these things in the doc. Currently using internal artisan server. Hence these configs doesn't come into the picture yet.